# Valid Logical Predicate Usage

Tags: logic

Hello StackExchange users.

I have constructed various basic mathematical logic expressions, and I would like for knowledgeable users on the website to inform me of their validity.

$L(a,b) = a < b$

$G(a,b) = a > b$

Let us assume that variable a = 10, and variable b = 20. This is the expression that I devised:

$L(b,a) \land G(a,b) \implies (a + b) = 30$

I am attempting to assert that if 'b' is lesser than 'a' and 'a' is greater than 'b', thence the sum of 'a' and 'b' is equivalent to thirty, using the above variable definitions as the given context.

I originally interpreted the expression as "true." Please help me revise my logic reasoning capabilities by informing of whether this is accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: $L(b,a)$ is equivalent to $G(a,b)$, so $L(b,a) \land G(a,b)$  is equivalent to $G(a,b)$.

Second: if $a = 10$, and $b = 20$ then $(a + b) = 30$ is true and as
$$\text{anything}\implies\text{true}$$
([verum sequitur ex quodlibet](http://open.conted.ox.ac.uk/sites/open.conted.ox.ac.uk/files/resources/Create%20Document/LOG_HO4.pdf)), your expression is true

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I was trying to determine if I used the predicates properly.